# Extracting and Using Sensor in Camera Assembly of Nokia Lumia 1020

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-1020

I am trying to use the awesome camera sensor in the Nokia Lumia 1020 for research purposes.

Unfortunately, my screen is broken so the screen is completely black. The 3 keys at the bottom (The back, windows and search keys) still work, but I don't know if the touch screen is still working. I tried projecting the phone to a PC using the Project my Screen app, but I still need to press the "allow screen projection" button on my phone, and that is proving difficult since I can't see anything.

So my question is: is it possible to disassemble the phone, extract the camera assembly out of the phone, and use the camera sensor remotely, when it is severed from the phone itself? If so, what means are there to connect the camera assembly/sensor to my computer? Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Another option I came across would be to use a USB OTG adapter:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ6DnxJ9nU0

Would this work for a Nokia Lumia phone?

Comment: I think it's probably a lot less work to just get the screen fixed, no?

Comment: But a lot more expensive too. :P
Plus, I just need the camera, not the phone itself

Comment: Sounds more to me like an [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) question, than a Windows Phone one?